# Elasticsearch match_phrase_query with space don't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a problem when i make a match_phrase_query with a string containing space, but not always =/

3 examples  :

1/

```
  {
    "query" : {
              "match_phrase_prefix" : {
                "username" : {
                  "query":"maury"
                }
              }
    }
}
```

This first example works and give me results.

2/

```
  {
    "query" : {
              "match_phrase_prefix" : {
                "username" : {
                  "query":"maury chelsea"
                }
              }
    }
}
```

This second example, with full name works too.

3/

```
  {
    "query" : {
              "match_phrase_prefix" : {
                "username" : {
                  "query":"maury ch"
                }
              }
    }
}
```

This exemple didn't work, i have no result return. I didn't understand because it's working with 1 word, and 2 words, with the 2nd word having minimum 3-4 characters, depending of the name of the person i search.

Have you already encounter this problem ?

Thanks you, Ludovic

Comment: This might be because you have a lot of terms starting with `ch`. Try adding the `max_expansions` parameter which defaults to 50 and increase it to (e.g.) 100 to see if you get a result or not. The [official doc explains](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) why you're running into this issue.

Comment: Please don't append _resolved_ to the title. Marking an answer as accepted tells others that this question has now been solved. Please take the [tour] for further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a lot of terms starting with `ch`. Try adding the `max_expansions` parameter (which defaults to 50) and increase it to (e.g.) 100 to see if you get a result or not.

```
  {
    "query" : {
              "match_phrase_prefix" : {
                "username" : {
                  "query":"maury ch",
                  "max_expansions": 100     <--- add this
                }
              }
    }
}
```

The [official doc explains](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) why you're running into this issue.